# Passing data to handlebars - node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am new to node.js , so basically I am making a get request in my router(index.js) and then after I get the result (I could see that I obtained the right result by dumping it in console.log) I am parsing it into a json object and passing it to a render function so that I could use it there, however, I am getting errors. I will post the code segments and the JSON fragment below . Is this the right way to use handlebars?

**Router (index.js)**

```
router.get('/getusers', function(req, res) {
    wrapRequestAsCallback(req.cookies.TOKEN_CACHE_KEY, {

        onSuccess: function(token) {
            var all_users = {};
            // get all the users
            requestUtil.getJson(
                'graph.microsoft.com',
                '/v1.0/users',
                token.accessToken,
                function(result) {
                    if (result !== null) {
                        console.log(result);
                        all_users = JSON.parse(result);
                        req.session.all_users = all_users;
                        if (all_users !== null) {
                            res.render('display_all_users', all_users);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            res.status(err.code);
            console.log(err.message);
            res.send();
        }
    });
});
```

**JSON Object**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$skiptoken=X%27445370740200010000001B3A4150432E4167656E744074686577696E6567726F7572D303037332D343865352D396432332D633438383336613833636361B900000000000000000000%27",
    "value": [{
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "ABC DEF",
            "givenName": "ABC",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "Abc.Def@somemail.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "DEF",
            "userPrincipalName": "abc.def@somemail.com",
            "id": "abcd1"
        }, {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "ABC XYZ",
            "givenName": "ABC",
            "jobTitle": "Shipping Clerk",
            "mail": "Abc.Xyz@somemail.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": "Stockton",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "XYZ",
            "userPrincipalName": "abc.xyz@somemail.com",
            "id": "abcd2"
        }
        .....
    }] }
```

**display_all_users.hbs**

```
<h2 class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontWeight-semibold"> EMPLOYEE DETAILS: </h2>
<div class="ms-TextField">
    <p> {{all_users.value[0].displayName}} </p>
</div>
```

I need to go through all user details, but for test purpose I was trying to access the display name of first user returned but I am getting this error:

```
Error: C:\test\views\display_all_users.hbs: Parse error on line 15:
...    <p> {{all_users.value[0].displayName
-----------------------^

    Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
    at Object.parseError(C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ node_modules\ handlebars\ dist\ cjs\ handlebars\ compiler\ parser.js: 150: 11)
    at Object.parse(C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ node_modules\ handlebars\ dist\ cjs\ handlebars\ compiler\ parser.js: 202: 22)
    at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse(C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ node_modules\ handlebars\ dist\ cjs\ handlebars\ compiler\ base.js: 25: 30)
    at compileInput(C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ node_modules\ handlebars\ dist\ cjs\ handlebars\ compiler\ compiler.js: 451: 19)
    at ret(C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ node_modules\ handlebars\ dist\ cjs\ handlebars\ compiler\ compiler.js: 460: 18)
    at C: \test\ node_modules\ hbs\ lib\ hbs.js: 63: 19
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose[as oncomplete](fs.js: 380: 3)
```

Comment: have you try this `res.render('display_all_users', {all_users: all_users});` ?

Comment: yes I tried and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I even tried res.render('display_all_users', {data: all_users}); and tried accessing it in the handlebar as data.value[0].displayName, but still the same result

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I got a similar error when my each helper had a space before the '#each' and '/each'

Comment: @HectorBarbossa: There's no space between #each and /each in my code, but still, I haven't been able to figure out what went wrong

Comment: Don't Stackoverflow team have answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to render your node.js result to your handlebars template like this:

```
res.render('display_all_users', {all_users: all_users});
```

Once you have "all_users" availale you can get the value like this:

```
{{#each all_users}}
        <tr>
              <td headers="name">{{all_users.value[0].displayName}}</td>

         </tr>

 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Well, I just tried, but I am still getting the same error. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: `<td headers="name">{{value[0].displayName}}</td>`

Comment: A different, but almost the same kind of error:



Error: C:\test\views\display_all_users.hbs: Parse error on line 19:
...td headers="name">{{value[0].displayName
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
   at Object.parseError (C:\test\node_modules\hbs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\parser.js:150:11)
   at Object.parse (C:\test\node_modules\hbs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\parser.js:202:22)

Comment: What it prints when you write {{all_users}} and  <td>{{all_users}}.value}}

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. Here is how I solved it

```
{{#each all_users}}
  <tr>
    <td headers="name">{{displayName}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Remove all the `value[0]` stuff etc. Above code will work fine.